# Android Profiler: Application is not debuggable

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, native

I would like to analyze Memory and CPU performances of my game, which was developed with Marmalade for Cross Platform support .. in C++.

When I import the debug APK into Profiler, it does not allow me to Debug the Application.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> Application is not debuggable.

But this cannot be true, as this is my debug version of the game.

The device is recognized by Android Studio and it has USB Debugging ON.

I had to add some *Native Lib Symbols* for my game, but not all were succesfully added - I received

> Unable to find debug symbols in file

But I think that is only if you want to debug your application using Breakpoints and similar. I only want to see Android Profiler's performance stats.

If I `RUN` the project / APK, it succesfully launched on my attached Device.

Got any suggestions what I should try?